# html script links. type = "text/javascript"

Tags: html

Where does the "text" come from? i.e. Why are links described as "text/..."?

I get that you are telling the browser what script to use for script tags.. (is this right?) and that the default language in most browsers is javascript making this line superfluous. However this looks to me like the html is describing a linked file as "a type of text called javascript". Or if you used type = "text/css", then the html is linking to a type of text called css. what else would you use other than "text"?

Comment: [MIME types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at [W3's documentation on content types](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html), we discover that there are 8 types:

- text
- application
- audio
- image
- message
- multipart
- x-token
- video

`text` here is the *type* and JavaScript, in your example, is the *subtype*:

```
Content-Type := type "/" subtype *[";" parameter]
```

This document then goes on to define what `text` is:

> text: textual information.
>
> The primary subtype, "plain", indicates plain (unformatted) text. No special software is required to get the full meaning of the text, aside from support for the indicated character set. Subtypes are to be used for enriched text in forms where application software may enhance the appearance of the text, but such software must not be required in order to get the general idea of the content. Possible subtypes thus include any readable word processor format. A very simple and portable subtype, richtext, is defined in this document.

`text/javascript` itself is actually obsolete, and `application/javascript` should be used instead (however not all browsers will understand what `application/javascript` is, so the former is much more common).

In HTML5, the `type` attribute is optional on the `script` element, and omitting it is perfectly fine:

```
<script src="myScript.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The file is expressed in text as opposed to, for instance, a JPEG.

That said, the `text/javascript` MIME type is deprecated in favour of `application/javascript` since the format isn't primarily  intended to be read as text (unlike HTML, which is text with markup around it).

The [other registries](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) are:

- application
- audio
- example
- image
- message
- model
- multipart
- text
- video